# Использование grpc для межсервисного взаимодействия

Tags: grpc, микросервисы

Как правильно использовать grpc для взаимодействия нескольких сервисов. С помощью grpc мы можем удаленно вызывать процедуры в другом сервисе, но что если таких сервисов несколько, к примеру, сервис1 должен вызввать процедуры на сервисе2 и сервисе3, каким образом будет реализовано это взаимодействие, для взаимодействия с каждым сервисом будут созданы отдельные классы ? А если другие сервисы могут вызывать процедуры на сервисе1, он будет выступать как в качествие клиента, так и в качестве сервиса? Получается, для одно сервиса(если это сервис API, первый в цепочке) будет необходимо описывать большое количество .proto файлов? Если есть возможность, приведите пожалуйста пример взаимодействия между несколькими сервисами.

Comment: Не могу ничего сказать про технологию, что вы испольщуете, но из моего опыта, когда создается микросервис, также создается для него клиент (библиотека). Например, `MyMictoservice` - как бекенд сервер и `MyMicroserviceJavaClient` как библиотека классов. Таким образом любой другой сервис может добавить себе в зависимости этот клиент и вызывать методы мткросервиса через него. Какой именно протокол будет при этом использоваться - зависит от реализации клиента и вызывающему микросервису это должно быть неважно.